# Replace all the text in all columns except the last

Tags: perl, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a data file that reads

```
field1 field2 diseased 
discrete discrete   discrete                                                    
                    class
No Yes No 
Yes Yes Yes
No No No
```

I want to replace No in all columns except the last column with a question mark (?). This is just a toy example with three columns I have data with thousands of columns. So, doing individually will not make sense. Also first three lines are headers and I want them as is. So I want my result to be

```
field1 field2 diseased 
discrete discrete   discrete                                                    
                    class
? Yes No 
Yes Yes Yes
? ? No
```

I want to do this without changing the formatting of the file. So far I can do this by deleting the last column and replacing No and again appending the last line but that loses formatting. Also Thanks for the help.
In some cases when there are large numbers of Yes and last column is No, some tabs are added in the end. Command

```
cat -e test
```

results in

```
field1 field2 diseased 
discrete discrete   discrete                                                    
                    class
? Yes No$
Yes Yes Yes
? ? No
Yes Yes No $
```

I don't want space between last No and $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} {for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i=="No") $i="?"}1' a
?       Yes     No 
Yes     Yes     Yes
?       ?       No
```

It checks from 1st to penultimate field and does the replacement if necessary.

`BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}` is used to set the input and output field separator as tab.

Comment: Interestingly, my file is tab delimited and it changes to space delimited file. But the problem is if there is Yes in all columns, tab delimited file stays. Is there an easy way to fix that??

Comment: @lovedynasty `BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}`

Comment: @lovedynasty yes, sure, just updated with the block `BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}`. Hope it helps

Comment: @jkshah wow, was just updating with this when I saw your commenting it hehe

Comment: @fedorqui I guess it should be    'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} atleast in bash

Comment: @lovedynasty `OFS` stands for Output Field Separator, while `FS` will be (input) Field Separator. It is good practice to write it in case your file format will change some day. Anyway, just `BEGIN{OFS="\t"}` suffices for this case, yes.

Comment: Actually, not 
 
If there is a column with all yes and last column No, it adds a tab after No. Otherwise, its fine. Any way to address that? Yes Yes Yes No No Yes No No cat -e file would produce Yes Yes Yes No $ ? Yes ? No$

Comment: @lovedynasty please update your question with this sample input and expected output. In comments format cannot be seen.

Comment: @lovedynasty I am not going to follow on this unless you give proper explanations. Note both anubhava and me we are checking it and you go from one answer to another trying to figure out things without explaining properly.

Comment: Sorry it was problem with the source ... in other cases there aren't, but in all yes cases there are. Sorry !! Now it works

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have some other headers which can risk matching `No`, you should get away with something really simple, such as:

```
perl -pwe 's/\bNo\b(?!\s*$)/?/g' infile > outfile
```

Which will replace all `No` strings that have word boundaries around them. Shell redirection will store the output in a new file. You may also make use of the `-i` switch, but I normally do not recommend it to new users.

Using a negative lookahead assertion to make sure it is not the last match on the line.

Comment: Doesn't produce desired output. Replaces even in last column.

Comment: Aha, I did not see that. Well, that is easily fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Use awk:

```
awk -v ccol=3 '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i != ccol && $i=="No") $i="?"} 1' OFS='\t' file
```

You can pass any value for `ccol` to skip that column to be replaced.

Comment: Interestingly, my file is tab delimited and it changes to space delimited file. But the problem is if there is Yes in all columns, tab delimited file stays. Is there an easy way to fix that??

Comment: Yes see the edited command now that uses `OFS='\t'` to make output tab delimited.

Comment: @lovedynasty: Of course this awk command doesn't assume that only last column needs to be skipped since you can pass col # as an argument.

Comment: If there is a column with all yes like and last column No, it adds a tab after No. Otherwise, its fine. Any way to address that?
    Yes Yes Yes No
    No Yes No No

cat -e file would produce  Yes Yes Yes No $
? Yes ? No$

Comment: Let me try to address that.

Comment: Can you please provide your sample input by editing your question since I could not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have space between `No` and `$` in original file?

Comment: Sorry it was problem with the source ... in other cases there aren't, but in all yes cases there are. Sorry !!

Answer (score 1):

Here I consider that the last column mustn't be replaced (this could be easily adapted if necessary).

Using awk :

```
[ ~]$ awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++){if ($i=="No"){$i="?"}}; print $0}' test.txt 
field1 field2 diseased 
discrete discrete   discrete                                                    
                    class
? Yes No
Yes Yes Yes
? ? No
```

Using sed :

```
[ ~]$ sed "s/No/\?/g; s/\?\ *$/No/g" test.txt 
field1 field2 diseased 
discrete discrete   discrete                                                    
                class
? Yes No
Yes Yes Yes
? ? No
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
awk '$1=="No" {$1="?"} $2=="No" {$2="?"} 1' file
```

Comment: Note there can be way more than 3 columns.